# How can I add a class to all form groups that have an empty input inside?

Tags: jquery

By click on my button "make pink" I want to highlight the input fields, that do not have any text inside:

```js
$("#highlight").click(function () {
  $('.form-group input').blur(function() {
   if (!$(this).val()) {
     $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="input">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="input" value="Some Text">
</div>

<button id="highlight">Make pink</button>
```

Not adding the class, and I do not know why

Comment: Your code works as expected once you focus out input. So what is your expected behaviour???

Comment: The code is working...

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, I totally forgot to add my button. So I am expecting by click on my button to highlight only the input that has no text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the inputs to turn pink as soon as you click the button. However, you have a `blur` event nested inside your `click` event. Meaning that once you click the button, it then binds the `blur` event to the inputs and waits for that to happen. So if you click the button then click one of your inputs and click away, it will turn pink.

To get it to happen immediately on click, get rid of that blur event and change it to something like this, which is using jQuery's `each` function:

```
$("#highlight").click(function () {
  $('.form-group input').each(function() {
   if (!$(this).val()) {
     $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,

```
$('.form-group input').blur(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value == "" || value == undefined) {
          $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      }
 });
```

Comment: No, value would never be `undefined`. This is exact same behaviour as OP's code (which btw works as expected)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you have to check it this way

```
$(this).attr('value') === ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by 'form-group' rather than selecting its parent only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .has-error {
      background-color: pink
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.form-group input').blur(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" id="input">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" id="input" value="Some Text">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add to my question, that I need the highlighting by a button click. So I updated my question now